# remove repeated elements in a python list

Tags: python

I have a list of strings in which there are a lot of repeated items. I would like to make a new list in which all items are present but there is only one occurrence of each item.

input:

```
mylist = ["hg", "yt", "hg", "tr", "yt"]
```

output:

```
newlist = ["hg", "yt", "tr"]
```

I actually have tried this code but did not return what I want:

```
newlist = []
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    if mylist[i+1] == mylist[i]:
        newlist.append(mylist[i])
```

Comment: ls = list(set(mylist))

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```
newlist = set(mylist)
```

Or, to retrieve exactly a `list`, but is can be useless depending what you are doing with:

```
nexlist = list(set(mylist))
```

Comment: This is only appropriate if ordering is not significant.

Comment: It is not asked to keep it ordered. But I added more explanations if it is the wanted behavior.

Comment: irder is not important

Comment: @Tiger-222 eh? `set`s are not ordered in Python 3.6, not even as an implementation detail, your thinking of `dict`s

Comment: Wow, it seems I mixed informations in my brain. Thank you for the update.